# How to repeat the script up to 100 times with 100 other values

Tags: javascript, jquery, repeat

```js
$("#a_b001").mouseover(function() {
  $("#a_p001").show();
  $("#a_bor001").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("#a_p001").hide();
  $("#a_bor001").hide();
});
$("#a_b002").mouseover(function() {
  $("#a_p002").show();
  $("#a_bor002").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("#a_p002").hide();
  $("#a_bor002").hide();
});
$("#a_b003").mouseover(function() {
  $("#a_p003").show();
  $("#a_bor003").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("#a_p003").hide();
  $("#a_bor001").hide();
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b_act_p_1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  width: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 124px;
  left: -104px;
}

.b_act_p_2 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  width: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 124px;
  left: -90px;
}

.b_act_p_3 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  width: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 124px;
  left: -74px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-frame top_s_b_d" id="b_seg_c">
  <svg width="488" height="168">
      <g transform="translate(16 16)">
        <g class="hour-axis" transform="translate(18 124)" opacity="1">
          <g transform="translate(-0.5 0)">
            <line y2="4" stroke="#9e9e9e" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></line>
            <text y="8" fill="#9e9e9e" dominant-baseline="hanging" text-anchor="start">12 AM</text>
          </g>
          <g transform="translate(107.5 0)">
            <line y2="4" stroke="#9e9e9e" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></line>
            <text y="8" fill="#9e9e9e" dominant-baseline="hanging" text-anchor="middle">6 AM</text>
          </g>
          <g transform="translate(215.5 0)">
            <line y2="4" stroke="#9e9e9e" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></line>
            <text y="8" fill="#9e9e9e" dominant-baseline="hanging" text-anchor="middle">12 PM</text>
          </g>
          <g transform="translate(323.5 0)">
            <line y2="4" stroke="#9e9e9e" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></line>
            <text y="8" fill="#9e9e9e" dominant-baseline="hanging" text-anchor="middle">6 PM</text>
          </g>
          <g transform="translate(431.5 0)">
            <line y2="4" stroke="#9e9e9e" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></line>
            <text y="8" fill="#9e9e9e" dominant-baseline="hanging" text-anchor="end">12 AM</text>
          </g>
          <line x1="-4" x2="434" y1="0.5" y2="0.5" stroke="#9e9e9e"></line>
        </g>
        <g class="day-axis" opacity="1">
          <text y="8" x="12" fill="#9e9e9e" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">M</text>
          <text y="26" x="12" fill="#9e9e9e" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">T</text>
          <text y="44" x="12" fill="#9e9e9e" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">W</text>
          <text y="62" x="12" fill="#9e9e9e" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">T</text>
          <text y="80" x="12" fill="#9e9e9e" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">F</text>
          <text y="98" x="12" fill="#9e9e9e" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">S</text>
          <text y="116" x="12" fill="#9e9e9e" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">S</text>
          <line x1="17.5" x2="17.5" y1="-4" y2="128" stroke="#9e9e9e"></line>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(18 0)" class="square-area">
          <rect id="a_b001" class="square hour-0 day-6" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="0" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect id="a_b002" class="square hour-1 day-6" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="18" y="108" style="border: 2px #333 solid;" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect id="a_b003" class="square hour-2 day-6" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="36" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-3 day-6" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="54" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-4 day-6" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="72" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-5 day-6" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="90" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-6 day-6" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="108" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-7 day-6" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="126" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-8 day-6" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="144" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-9 day-6" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="162" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-10 day-6" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="180" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-11 day-6" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="198" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-12 day-6" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="216" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-13 day-6" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="234" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-14 day-6" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="252" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-15 day-6" fill="rgba(171,201,250,1)" x="270" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-16 day-6" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="288" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-17 day-6" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="306" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-18 day-6" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="324" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-19 day-6" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="342" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-20 day-6" fill="rgba(161,194,250,1)" x="360" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-21 day-6" fill="rgba(150,187,249,1)" x="378" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-22 day-6" fill="rgba(98,153,246,1)" x="396" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-23 day-6" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="414" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-0 day-0" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="0" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-1 day-0" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="18" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-2 day-0" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="36" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-3 day-0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="54" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-4 day-0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="72" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-5 day-0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="90" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-6 day-0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="108" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-7 day-0" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="126" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-8 day-0" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="144" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-9 day-0" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="162" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-10 day-0" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="180" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-11 day-0" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="198" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-12 day-0" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="216" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-13 day-0" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="234" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-14 day-0" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="252" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-15 day-0" fill="rgba(161,194,250,1)" x="270" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-16 day-0" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="288" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-17 day-0" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="306" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-18 day-0" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="324" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-19 day-0" fill="rgba(182,208,251,1)" x="342" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-20 day-0" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="360" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-21 day-0" fill="rgba(171,201,250,1)" x="378" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-22 day-0" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="396" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-23 day-0" fill="rgba(66,133,244,1)" x="414" y="0" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-0 day-1" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="0" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-1 day-1" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="18" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-2 day-1" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="36" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-3 day-1" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="54" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-4 day-1" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="72" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-5 day-1" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="90" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-6 day-1" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="108" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-7 day-1" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="126" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-8 day-1" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="144" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-9 day-1" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="162" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-10 day-1" fill="rgba(182,208,251,1)" x="180" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-11 day-1" fill="rgba(161,194,250,1)" x="198" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-12 day-1" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="216" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-13 day-1" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="234" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-14 day-1" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="252" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-15 day-1" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="270" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-16 day-1" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="288" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-17 day-1" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="306" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-18 day-1" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="324" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-19 day-1" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="342" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-20 day-1" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="360" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-21 day-1" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="378" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-22 day-1" fill="rgba(171,201,250,1)" x="396" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-23 day-1" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="414" y="18" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-0 day-2" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="0" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-1 day-2" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="18" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-2 day-2" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="36" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-3 day-2" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="54" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-4 day-2" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="72" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-5 day-2" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="90" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-6 day-2" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="108" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-7 day-2" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="126" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-8 day-2" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="144" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-9 day-2" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="162" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-10 day-2" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="180" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-11 day-2" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="198" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-12 day-2" fill="rgba(171,201,250,1)" x="216" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-13 day-2" fill="rgba(150,187,249,1)" x="234" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-14 day-2" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="252" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-15 day-2" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="270" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-16 day-2" fill="rgba(161,194,250,1)" x="288" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-17 day-2" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="306" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-18 day-2" fill="rgba(161,194,250,1)" x="324" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-19 day-2" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="342" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-20 day-2" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="360" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-21 day-2" fill="rgba(171,201,250,1)" x="378" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-22 day-2" fill="rgba(182,208,251,1)" x="396" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-23 day-2" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="414" y="36" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-0 day-3" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="0" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-1 day-3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="18" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-2 day-3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="36" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-3 day-3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="54" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-4 day-3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="72" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-5 day-3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="90" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-6 day-3" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="108" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-7 day-3" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="126" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-8 day-3" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="144" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-9 day-3" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="162" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-10 day-3" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="180" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-11 day-3" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="198" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-12 day-3" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="216" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-13 day-3" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="234" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-14 day-3" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="252" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-15 day-3" fill="rgba(171,201,250,1)" x="270" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-16 day-3" fill="rgba(171,201,250,1)" x="288" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-17 day-3" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="306" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-18 day-3" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="324" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-19 day-3" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="342" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-20 day-3" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="360" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-21 day-3" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="378" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-22 day-3" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="396" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-23 day-3" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="414" y="54" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-0 day-4" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="0" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-1 day-4" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="18" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-2 day-4" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="36" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-3 day-4" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="54" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-4 day-4" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="72" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-5 day-4" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="90" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-6 day-4" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="108" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-7 day-4" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="126" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-8 day-4" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="144" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-9 day-4" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="162" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-10 day-4" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="180" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-11 day-4" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="198" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-12 day-4" fill="rgba(171,201,250,1)" x="216" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-13 day-4" fill="rgba(171,201,250,1)" x="234" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-14 day-4" fill="rgba(129,174,248,1)" x="252" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-15 day-4" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="270" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-16 day-4" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="288" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-17 day-4" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="306" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-18 day-4" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="324" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-19 day-4" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="342" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-20 day-4" fill="rgba(182,208,251,1)" x="360" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-21 day-4" fill="rgba(171,201,250,1)" x="378" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-22 day-4" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="396" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-23 day-4" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="414" y="72" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-0 day-5" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="0" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-1 day-5" fill="rgba(245,248,254,1)" x="18" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-2 day-5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="36" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-3 day-5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="54" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-4 day-5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="72" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-5 day-5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="90" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-6 day-5" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="108" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-7 day-5" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="126" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-8 day-5" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="144" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-9 day-5" fill="rgba(182,208,251,1)" x="162" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-10 day-5" fill="rgba(161,194,250,1)" x="180" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-11 day-5" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="198" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-12 day-5" fill="rgba(182,208,251,1)" x="216" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-13 day-5" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="234" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-14 day-5" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="252" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-15 day-5" fill="rgba(192,214,251,1)" x="270" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-16 day-5" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="288" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-17 day-5" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="306" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-18 day-5" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="324" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-19 day-5" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="342" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-20 day-5" fill="rgba(224,235,253,1)" x="360" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-21 day-5" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="378" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-22 day-5" fill="rgba(213,228,253,1)" x="396" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect class="square hour-23 day-5" fill="rgba(203,221,252,1)" x="414" y="90" height="16" width="16"></rect>
          <rect id="a_bor001" x="0" y="108" height="16" width="16" fill="none" stroke="#222" style="display: none;"></rect>
          <rect id="a_bor002" x="18" y="108" height="16" width="16" fill="none" stroke="#222" style="display: none;"></rect>
          <rect id="a_bor003" x="36" y="108" height="16" width="16" fill="none" stroke="#222" style="display: none;"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="b_act_p_1" id="a_p001" style="display: none;">Testtt</div>
<div class="b_act_p_2" id="a_p002" style="display: none;">Testtt</div>
<div class="b_act_p_3" id="a_p003" style="display: none;">Testtt</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/konradstrek/1e9sLr8c/12/). For each single block I want to display new popup. Total 168 unique popups.

I have the following script below:

```
<script>
$("#a_b001").mouseover(function() {
  $("#a_p001").show();
  $("#a_bor001").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("#a_p001").hide();
  $("#a_bor001").hide();
});
</script>
```

And I'm trying to repeat this script up to 100 consecutive numbers, for example:
(001, 002, 003, 004, ..., 098, 099, 100). It's possible to use `for` in this repetition?

```
<script>
$("#a_b001").mouseover(function() {
  $("#a_p001").show();
  $("#a_bor001").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("#a_p001").hide();
  $("#a_bor001").hide();
});
$("#a_b002").mouseover(function() {
  $("#a_p002").show();
  $("#a_bor002").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("#a_p002").hide();
  $("#a_bor002").hide();
});
$("#a_b003").mouseover(function() {
  $("#a_p003").show();
  $("#a_bor003").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("#a_p003").hide();
  $("#a_bor003").hide();
});
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below example

these are your hovering elements. every one contain data-id attribute which contains its id number.

```
<rect data-id="001" id="a_b001" class="square hour-0 day-6" fill="rgba(234,241,254,1)" x="0" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
            <rect data-id="002" id="a_b003" class="square hour-2 day-6" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="36" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
            <rect data-id="003" class="square hour-3 day-6" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" x="54" y="108" height="16" width="16"></rect>
```

These are hide/show div's

```
<div class="b_act_p" id="a_p001" style="display: none;">Testtt</div>
<div class="b_act_p" id="a_bor001" style="display: none;">Testtt</div>

<div class="b_act_p" id="a_p002" style="display: none;">Testtt</div>
<div class="b_act_p" id="a_bor002" style="display: none;">Testtt</div>

<div class="b_act_p" id="a_p003" style="display: none;">Testtt</div>
<div class="b_act_p" id="a_bor003" style="display: none;">Testtt</div>
```

This is js function

```
$(".square").mouseover(function() {

  var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); //returns hovering rect data-id

  $("#a_p"+id).show(); //concat id
  $("#a_bor"+id).show();

}).mouseout(function() {

   var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); //returns hovering rect data-id

   $("#a_p"+id).hide();
   $("#a_bor"+id).hide();

 });
```

Comment: I only did it for 3 rect's. make necessary changes

Comment: glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try below logic.

```
 <script>
var str = "";
for(var i = 1 ;i<=100;i++){
 str = "00"+i;

$("#a_b"+str).mouseover(function() {
  $("#a_p"+str).show();
  $("#a_bor"+str).show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $("#a_p"+str).hide();
  $("#a_bor"+str).hide();
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example for you .

```js
$(".myclass").mouseover(function() {
  var index=$(this).attr('index');
  $("#p_"+index).show();
  $("#bor_"+index).show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  var index=$(this).attr('index');
  $("#p_"+index).hide();
  $("#bor_"+index).hide();
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.myclass{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td index='1' class='myclass'>a</td>
  <td id='p_1' class='hidden'>aa</td>
  <td id='bor_1' class='hidden'>aaa</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td index='2' class='myclass'>b</td>
  <td id='p_2' class='hidden'>bb</td>
  <td id='bor_2' class='hidden'>bbb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td index='3' class='myclass'>c</td>
  <td id='p_3' class='hidden'>cc</td>
  <td id='bor_3' class='hidden'>ccc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td index='4' class='myclass'>d</td>
  <td id='p_4' class='hidden'>dd</td>
  <td id='bor_4' class='hidden'>ddd</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating N event listeners you should only create 1 based upon the class.

These are different elements that share a common behaviour. By design they should also share some visual element(s).

You can create a CSS class that you put on all these elements and add the listener of the class. Lets say that the class is 'button'.
Then something like this should do it.

```
function getNumber(id) {
    return id.substr(id.indexOf("a_b") + 3);
}

$(".button").mouseover(function(e) {
    let number = getNumber(e.target.id); 

    $("#a_p" + number).show();
    $("#a_bor" + number).show();
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    let number = getNumber(e.target.id)

    $("#a_p" + number).hide();
    $("#a_p" + number).hide();
});
```